# ASP.NET Create Chart that can be tranlated using google translate

Tags: asp.net, charts, google-translate

As the title says I need a chart tool / idea that can create a chart on an HTML page so that when it is on the page using the Chrome built in Google translate feature, the text within the chart will be translated as well as the text surrounding the chart (i.e. normal page text).

All the commercial ones that I have found already (I am currently using Fusion Charts) all seem to render the actual chart as a SVG graphic or use the canvas element and thus when you try and translate it, it will not work as the chart is an image.

Any suggestions from anyone who may have had the same issue or ideas from people would be most welcome

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Image-charts founder here.*

You might want to give a try to a static image chart generator like [Image-Charts](https://www.image-charts.com) :)

[image]